# Add columns to select *

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

In SQL Server I used to do something like this to add extra columns to a select:

```
select *,
        case
        when w1.start_date < w2.start_date then
            to_date(w2.START_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - 1
        else
        to_date(w1.end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        end as end_date_modified
from WEIGHTED_AVERAGE w1
```

Yet the following in Oracle causes "ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected":

```
select *,
        case
        when w1.start_date < w2.start_date then
            to_date(w2.START_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - 1
        else
        to_date(w1.end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        end end_date_modified
from WEIGHTED_AVERAGE w1
```

I've searched all over but can't figure out how to achieve this in Oracle.

Comment: consider too, not using *, this may take more time up front, but can help to give you better error messages later if a column changes, or reduce the amount of transmitted data, as the table grows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
select w1.*,
        case
        when w1.start_date < w2.start_date then
            to_date(w2.START_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - 1
        else
        to_date(w1.end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
        end end_date_modified
from WEIGHTED_AVERAGE w1
```

Comment: @vitorfs - Just what I was looking for, thanks.  Have your first accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Amend the beginning of your SELECT to w1.*