# Convert from Oracle's RAW(16) to .NET's GUID using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How do I convert a Oracle Raw 16 to GUID in MSSQL? The following is not working in Oracle DB SQL Console,

```
select hextoraw(Raw16Column), *
from OracleDb.PRODUCTS
order by PRODUCTS_ID desc
fetch next 20 rows only
```

Error:

```
[42000][936] ORA-00936: missing expression Position: 23
```

Resources: [Convert from Oracle's RAW(16) to .NET's GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289734/convert-from-oracles-raw16-to-nets-guid)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions064.htm

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7289734/1509264 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/7993931/1509264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `*` and are also selecting other columns then you must prefix the `*` with the table name or alias (and you probably want `RAWTOHEX` rather than `HEXTORAW`):

```sql
select p.*,
       RAWTOHEX(raw16column)
from   PRODUCTS p
order by PRODUCTS_ID desc
fetch next 20 rows only
```

and, if you want to [convert it to a GUID with the correct endianess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289734/convert-from-oracles-raw16-to-nets-guid#comment117700150_7289991) then:

```sql
select p.*,
       SUBSTR(raw16column,7,2)
       ||SUBSTR(raw16column,5,2)
       ||SUBSTR(raw16column,3,2)
       ||SUBSTR(raw16column,1,2)
       ||'-'
       ||SUBSTR(raw16column,11,2)
       ||SUBSTR(raw16column,9,2)
       ||'-'
       ||SUBSTR(raw16column,15,2)
       ||SUBSTR(raw16column,13,2)
       ||'-'
       ||SUBSTR(raw16column,17,16)
         AS guid
from   PRODUCTS p
order by PRODUCTS_ID desc
fetch next 20 rows only
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1710e0429a5216e1a6fed9a2538b3537)*